# How to resize background image and text in Joomla with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am currently building a new site in Joomla 3.6.5 using Twitter Bootstrap. My site is currently on my localhost and I have attached an image of what I currently have but I am now trying to add bootstrap code in order to make this responsive and I am struggling with the section (image shown below)

[image]

What I would like to do is to stack this on top of each for the mobile version but the background image (attached as well) needs to resize as the screen becomes smaller.

Also would appreciate any advice on how to tackle issues with tablet screen sizes as ideally would like all three to show side by side or on top of each other but i am guessing there will be a lot of space on a tablet screen size.

[image]

My current html is the following:

```
<div id="mainbox" class="span12">
<div class="box1 span4">
<div class="boxes-img1"><img src="images/pic1.png" alt="" border="0" /></div>
<div class="boxes1">20 MINUTES REPAIRS</div>
<div class="boxestext1">We have a 20 Minute Repairs Service and all Minor Repairs are diagnosed while you wait. Upgrades are also provided and completed within 20 minutes!</div>
<div class="boxes-link1">READ MORE</div>
</div>
<div class="box2 span4">
<div class="boxes-img2"><img src="images/pic2.png" alt="" border="0" /></div>
<div class="boxes2">WALK-IN REPAIRS</div>
<div class="boxestext2">We have a Walk-In Repairs Service and all faults are diagnosed while you wait. Please bear in mind all Major Faults can take up 24/48 hours.</div>
<div class="boxes-link2">
<div class="boxes-linktxt2">READ MORE</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box3 span4">
<div class="boxes-img3"><img src="images/pic3.png" alt="" border="0" /></div>
<div class="boxes3">BUY MOBILE PHONES</div>
<div class="boxestext3">All the latest models and great deals on Mobile Phones available, so visit our store today!</div>
<div class="boxes-link3">
<div class="boxes-linktxt3">READ MORE</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mainbox {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/box.png) no-repeat;
    height: 249px;
    width: 100%;
    }

div.box1{
  position: relative;
}

div.boxes1 {
  position:absolute;
    top:65px;
    left:0;
    margin: 0 0 29px 39px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Cabin-Bold'; /* no .ttf */
  font-style:italic;
    color:#fff;
  width: 268px;
    }

div.boxestext1 {
  position:absolute;
    top:115px;
    left:0;
    margin: 0 0 0 39px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open-Sans'; /* no .ttf */
    color:#7A869B;
    width: 268px;
    }

div.boxes-img1 {
  position:absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
    margin: 0 0 14px 125px;
  width: 268px;
    }

 div.boxes-link1 {
  display:block;
  background: url(../images/readmore.png) no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 14px 125px;
  position:absolute;
    top:221px;
    left:0;
  height: 37px;
  width: 84px;
  color:#FFF;
  text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Cabin'; /* no .ttf */
  padding: 10px 0 0 9px;
}

.boxes-link1:visited, .boxes-link1:hover, .boxes-link1:active {
  display:block;
  background: url(../images/readmoreover.png) no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 14px 125px;
  position:absolute;
    top:221px;
    left:0;
  height: 37px;
  width: 84px;
  color:#fc1300;
  text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Cabin'; /* no .ttf */
  padding: 10px 0 0 9px;
}

div.box2{
  position: relative;
}

div.boxes2 {
  position:absolute;
    top:65px;
    left: 310px;
    margin: 0 0 29px 39px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Cabin-Bold'; /* no .ttf */
  font-style:italic;
    color:#fff;
  width: 268px;
    }

div.boxestext2 {
  position:absolute;
    top:115px;
    left: 310px;
    margin: 0 0 0 39px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open-Sans'; /* no .ttf */
    color:#7A869B;
    width: 268px;
    }

div.boxes-img2 {
  position:absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left: 310px;
    margin: 0 0 14px 125px;
  width: 268px;
    }

div.boxes-link2 {
  position:absolute;
    top:221px;
    left:310px;
    margin: 0 0 14px 125px;
  height: 37px;
  width: 268px;
  background: url(../images/readmore.png) no-repeat;
}

div.boxes-linktxt2 {
  margin: 10px 0 0 9px;
  text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Cabin'; /* no .ttf */
  color:#FFF;
}
/* 2 BOXES END */

div.box3{
  position: relative;
}

div.boxes3 {
  position:absolute;
    top:65px;
    right:0;
    margin: 0 39px 29px 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Cabin-Bold'; /* no .ttf */
  font-style:italic;
    color:#fff;
  width: 268px;
    }

div.boxestext3 {
  position:absolute;
    top:115px;
    right:0;
    margin: 0 39px 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open-Sans'; /* no .ttf */
    color:#7A869B;
    width: 268px;
    }

div.boxes-img3 {
  position:absolute;
    top:-40px;
    right:0;
    margin: 0 -50px 14px 0;
  width: 268px;
    }

div.boxes-link3 {
  position:absolute;
    top:221px;
    right:0;
    margin: 0 -50px 14px 0;
  height: 37px;
  width: 268px;
  background: url(../images/readmore.png) no-repeat;
}

div.boxes-linktxt3 {
  margin: 10px 0 0 9px;
  text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Cabin'; /* no .ttf */
  color:#FFF;
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is "Twitter Bootstrap" a Joomla theme, by any chance?

Comment: The Twitter Bootstrap is not a theme, I have integrated the twitter bootstrap files in order to allow me to make the site responsive.

Comment: Well, the Twitter Bootstrap files you integrated are a refactored version of the real Twitter Bootstrap, with all its classes renamed. You'll find a lot of people who know Twitter Bootstrap but not so many who know... whatever it is you integrated. Is there a refactoring map available, where one could see what each class was mapped to?

Comment: From outside it really looks like the Joomla guys feel the need to reinvent the wheel. If they integrated Twitter Bootstrap as is, a lot of people would have been able to help you. And you could have benefited from the extensive documentation and examples available for Twitter Bootstrap. By refactoring it and renaming classes, it's only those familiar with this refactoring that can provide help. That's not exactly beneficial for their users. I suppose it's beneficial for them if they charge for "help".

Answer (score 0):

i think that the above approach is completely wrong.

First of all you should use col-xx-xx grid style

Take a look at this [Bootstrap Grid Options](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options)
using this grid style would solve your problems with viewports

As for the bg image in the #mainbox try using `object-fit:cover;`